# visNetwork R: Specify variable node background colour and border colour

Tags: r, networking, visnetwork

I would like to be able to vary the background colour of the nodes in my graph, and also use a border colour to ensure nicely marked-out nodes compared to edges.

I thought that the following should work, but it does not:

```
nodes <- data.frame(id = 1:3,
                    color = c("lightblue","red","blue"))
edges <- data.frame(from = c(1,2), to = c(1,3))
visNetwork(nodes, edges) %>% visNodes(color = list(border = "black"))
```

Resultant network

[image]

I tried providing a vector of colors directly to visNodes, which failed. Indeed the colors are retained from the data.frame column color

```
visNetwork(nodes, edges) %>% visNodes(color = list(background = c("yellow","pink","blue"), 
border = "black"))
```

Resultant network

[image]

visNetwork is a great package but is under queried on StackOverflow.

I'm posting this here on behalf of [Charlie from GitHub](https://github.com/datastorm-open/visNetwork/issues/51) after asking for due permission, primarily to have this available on StackOverflow for other R viz enthusiasts to get their answers here.

I had to post hyperlinks to pictures since I'm new to StackOverflow with a profile (Have used it for years as an Analytics Consultant, but didn't think about creating a profile, didn't know the use for it) and am not allowed to post images before collecting 10 reputation points.

Answer (score 0):

This case is interesting. First, we can pass individual options to nodes/edges data.frame, and global option for all nodes / edges with visNodes and visEdges.

So you can't do that :

```
visNetwork(nodes, edges) %>% visNodes(color = list(background = c("yellow","pink","blue"), 
border = "black"))
```

But just assign one background and border color with this way :

```
visNetwork(nodes, edges) %>% visNodes(color = list(background = "blue", 
border = "black"))
```

`color` can be a simple option with one value, or have a more complex definition. In your first example, it seems that the definition of `color` in data.frame overwrite the `visNodes` options.

Since 0.2.1, you can now pass complex options (list) directly in data.frame like this :

```
nodes <- data.frame(id = 1:3,
                    color.background = c("lightblue","red","blue"),
                    color.border = "black")
edges <- data.frame(from = c(1,2), to = c(1,3))
visNetwork(nodes, edges)
```

and so :

```
nodes <- data.frame(id = 1:3,
                    color.background = c("lightblue","red","blue"))
edges <- data.frame(from = c(1,2), to = c(1,3))
visNetwork(nodes, edges) %>% visNodes(color = list(border = "black"))
```

PS: Posting an answer myself since this conversation was available on GitHub issues already. Just wanted to document it here for the community's ease.